# SQL Error While Installing Magento 1.7.0.2 Without Sample Data

Tags: magento, installation

While installing magento 1.7.0.2 without sample data I'm getting the following error

> Blockquote
>   Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\magentojs\app\code\core\Mage\SalesRule\sql\salesrule_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'period'

Is there a known solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

in install-1.6.0.0.php you have

```
->addColumn('period', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array(
'nullable' => false,
), 'Period')
```

provide a default value that means replace above code by

```
->addColumn('period', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array(
'nullable' => false,
'default' => '0000-00-00',
), 'Period')
```