# magento : exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

Tags: magento

I am currently using Magento version 1.7.0.2_2. While installing it's showing following errors:

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1970080033

Error in file says:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:206:"Error in file: 
"D:\websites\magento\app\code\core\Mage\SalesRule\sql\salesrule_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'period'"
;i:1;s:930:"
#0 D:\websites\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 D:\websites\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.3')
#2 D:\websites\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.3')
#3 D:\websites\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 D:\websites\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 D:\websites\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 D:\websites\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 D:\websites\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}"
;s:3:"url";s:9:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

p.s.: however each time it shows a different error record number

Comment: Check at var/report there will be file having name 1970080033.Open it and try to find out the issue

Comment: @Muk it's showing bunch of errors.. and i am new to Mgneto.couldn't get anything .

Comment: You can post them in your question.

Comment: @Emi yeah posted..donno why it shows in bold big fonts...

Comment: I don't think Magento is fully compatible with Windows, see the System Requirements http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements Anyway, I have one shop running on a windows machine, and it's unlikely that this is the reason for this error. How are you installing, via downloader or did you download the package completely?

Comment: yeah hope so..i actually got full package zip

Answer (score 32):

You can enable printing errors by renaming file `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml`. file location `magentoRootDirectory/errors/`

Comment: And on a live site, immedately reverse this as displaying stack traces can expose sensitive information like database login credentials, etc. and also breaks PCI-DSS rules. It's not that hard to use your SFTP client to access the var/report/ folder and find the file named with the number.

Answer (score 4):

Magento install error - Exception printing is disabled

Here is a known error which can occur when installing Magento:
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Here is the solution:

- Navigate to the "errors" folder.
- Change local.xml.sample to local.xml
- You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay.
- Open magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and look for:

  ```
  protected $_options = array(
  'cache_dir' => 'null',
  ```
- Change it to:

  ```
  protected $_options = array(
  'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
  ```
- Save it.
- Now the final step is to go create a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.
- That's it.

Answer (score 2):

i have cleared the magento cache, and it solved the problem ( i mean, in "**var**" folder, there are "**cache**" and "**sessions**", and i have deleted everything in those two folders. but at first backup of course).

Answer (score 0):

Googled for about 5 secs:

http://blog.magestore.com/2012/07/13/magento-blog-how-to-fix-the-error-%E2%80%9Cinvalid-default-value-for-period%E2%80%9D/

[SQL Error While Installing Magento 1.7.0.2 Without Sample Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602597/sql-error-while-installing-magento-1-7-0-2-without-sample-data)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the php execution time in php.ini file to 64000.