# Magento Error: Cannot send headers; headers already sent in public_html/lib/Mandrill/Mandrill/Exports.php

Tags: php, database, magento, exception

Whenever someone either requests a password change or completes checkout I am getting this exception page come up with an error code.

"There has been an error processing your request - Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."

I've been to the error file and it says:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:114:"
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/siteusername/public_html/lib/Mandrill/Mandrill/Exports.php, line 1
";i:1;s:1796:"
/home/siteusername/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(107): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('mysite.com', 302)
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(711): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('mysite.com')
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(689): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->setRedirectWithCookieCheck('*/*/', Array)
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(752): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirect('*/*/')
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->forgotPasswordPostAction()
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('forgotpasswordp...')
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/community/BalkeTechnologies/StoreMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
/home/siteusername/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/home/siteusername/public_html/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
{main}
";s:3:"url";s:37:"/customer/account/forgotpasswordpost/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Been stuck on this ages and can't find a solution.

Comment: To enable printing errors trying this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480310/magento-exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons

Comment: take a look in first line `lib/Mandrill/Mandrill/Exports.php` script, maybe you have space or newline symbol before `<?php` or any output made in this line, and thus, session cannot start properly

Comment: Taking out the spaces fixed the problem! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First line lib/Mandrill/Mandrill/Exports.php script had a space before the php opening tag.